# Is metatheory, providing proof of the incompleteness theorem, consistent?

Tags: lo.logic

Is  metatheory, considered as a formal system, that used to prove the First Incompleteness Theorem, consistent?

Comment: _Which_ metatheory?

Comment: one consistent suffice

Comment: How do you expect anyone to prove absolute consistency of a metatheory without relying on an even stronger metametatheory?  You seem to be asking for something impossible.

Comment: consistency is a subject matter of Incompleteness theorem

Answer (score 22):

Peano Arithmetic suffices to prove Godel's Theorem, and Peano Arithmetic is consistent, so yes.

If you don't believe Peano Arithmetic is consistent, then the question becomes:  What *do* you believe is consistent?   As you can see in the accepted answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118183/what-axioms-are-used-to-prove-godels-incompleteness-theorems), you can prove Godel's Theorem in [Primitive Recursive Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic), or even a bit less.  If you doubt that PRA is consistent, you'll be forced to doubt so much that any skepticism you might have about Godel's Theorem is probably among the least of your worries.

Comment: I think that PA or PRA do not suffices 
And I do not sure that they are consistent

Comment: That both these theories prove the incompleteness theorem is a standard fact. I’m afraid you should learn at least something about the subject before asking question.

Comment: my objections:

every sentence or statement form defines class of his own proofs(statement form for every individual for wich he provable)
and even classes of proofs between proofs an so on... 

after Godelization we obtain function that defines the Godel number of sentence(statement form) for sets/classes of Godel numbers of proofs and so on...

quantification over sets

higher order stuff

Thus we have higher-order metatheory obtained from first-order arithmetics after Godelization of sintax

Comment: The only objects manipulated in the proof of the incompleteness theorem are various finite strings, like formulas and proofs, which are easily encoded as numbers. There is nothing stopping you from thinking about sets of proofs and suchlike, but nothing of this sort is needed to prove Gödel’s theorem.

Comment: for proof needed Godelization

Comment: Gödelization is a representation of *finite* objects by numbers, it does not involve any infinite sets (which is what higher-order arithmetic is for). If you are worried that the *statement* of Gödel’s incompleteness theorem involves these finite objects rather than numbers, and therefore strictly speaking cannot be literally expressed in first-order arithmetic, you can take a reformulation of any of the theories mentioned employing finite sets instead of numbers as its basic objects. This is only a notational variant of the original theory, so it does not change its consistency strength.

Comment: I think this is principial point. In prove of the Incompleteness theorem there are two types of "numbers": numbers(individuals) and Godel numbers. And symbol # (out of Godelization and arithmetics).
Godel numbers are some kind of codes or "names" for classes, alike irrational, transcendental numbers in analysis(second-order arithmetics) are "names" for classes of convergences. But in case of Godelization this is more large entity.
When we meet Prov(#(P)) and Prov(#(Prov(#(P)))), in the Diagonal lemma prove, it is reminiscent of the Fixed-point theorems in analysis(higher-order).

Comment: related 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106507/godelization-of-the-statement-forms

Answer (score 12):

As already pointed out by Steven Landsburg, there are plenty of such theories if you stick to conventional mathematics. If you are some sort of an ultrafinitist,
the incompleteness theorem is provable in weak fragments of bounded arithmetic, such as $PV$ or $S^1_2$. These theories are interpretable in Robinson’s arithmetic $Q$, so as long as you accept that $Q$ is consistent, there is such a theory. Do you believe that for every natural numbers $n,m$, the number $\underbrace{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{2^m}}}}}}_n$ exists? Then $Q$ is consistent.

Comment: Actually I mean absolute consistency(not relative consistency,  equiconsistency)
We can not live on a volcano waiting for counterexample

Comment: So? Q is absolutely consistent.

Comment: We will always live on volcanos waiting for counterexamples. That is an inescapable fact of modern mathematics, demonstrated for us by Godel. Not only that, but mathematics might well devolve to something uninteresting and even boring if it were not so.

Comment:  @Lee Mosher:     amen

Comment: We may live on volcanos waiting for counterexample to the consistency of ZFC, but the situation here is quite different, as the theory in question is much weaker. What is true is that you cannot get *something* out of *nothing*. Max, can you tell us what *is* true in the metametatheory where you want the consistency of the metatheory to be shown? As I wrote, the consistency of, say, $S^1_2$, can be shown in an elementary metametatheory whose most strongest assumption is the totality of the iterated exponential. Are you stipulating that *that* is false? Then good luck.

Comment: Emil:  Good luck for what?

Comment: Good look with looking for a nontrivial consistent theory.