# Can any formal system prove its own consistency?

Tags: lo.logic

My curiosity was piqued by this discussion:

[Presburger Arithmetic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9864/presburger-arithmetic)

I'll state this question loosely (rather than formally in terms of first-order logic or another formal framework) but I think it's clear what I'm asking.

Is there any formal system that can prove its own consistency?

PA is essentially too *strong* to prove its own consistency.  The choice of axioms makes the theory "too complicated" a structure for it to be able to deal with itself in this way.

(From my limited understanding) Presburger arithmetic is too *weak* to prove its own consistency.  Indeed the question of its consistency is not representable within it.

Is there something in the middle?  A system powerful enough to represent a formula (or some other formal construct) stating that it itself is consistent, yet not *too* powerful to allow the second incompleteness theorem to take over?

Comment: Short answer: I don't know.  Longer answer.  I don't think anyone else knows either.  Given the amount of time that has elapsed and the number of researchers interested in consistency results, I think we would have heard of such a theory by now.  So I vote no.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.21

Comment: An _inconsistent_ formal system can! 

Comment: @Qiaochu: your comment makes me realise that stating my question formally is going to be harder than I initially imagined ...

Comment: Poking around, it seems that Dan Willard has worked on this question, and as far as I can make out with my amateur understanding the answer is "yes": http://www.cs.albany.edu/FacultyStaff/profiles/willard.htm

Comment: @Tom: doesn't Neel Krishnaswamis answer in the discussion you cite provide an answer?

Comment: @Michael: Yes!  I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Voting to close as no longer relevant, since the question is answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9864/presburger-arithmetic/10027#10027

Comment: Downvoting because this question is directly answered by the accepted answer of the question that motivated this one. Did Tom even read the other question's answer?