CH in non-set theoretic foundations
I asked this question on stack exchange and got little attention, barring a nice example I intend to look into. The original post can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4941233/1053681
I put it up for bounty twice and received no more useful attention, so I hoped to ask it here and remedy that.
I understand the continuum hypothesis and the fact that it's independent of ZFC, but what about other foundations of math? For example, what does it look like in a type theoretic foundation? Is it still independent? In particular, I'd be very excited to see some type of construction of CH in alternate foundations, type theory or otherwise. Or even other set theories, although I'm certainly less interested in that. I understand that this question is potentially rather broad and complicated, so I'd be happy to simply be provided with references which discuss this, as opposed to full answers, if that's preferred. I greatly appreciate your help!
Note: I also wonder about the sensibility of the question in the first place, in that CH regards the existence of certain cardinals, but I'm not sure how the notion of cardinality may change in alternate foundations, or if these changes have a notable semantic difference.

The continuum hypothesis is answered positively assuming the axiom of constructibility.  Essentially, this is a good axiom if you assume that there are no new ways to construct sets than the ones we are used to (pairing, powerset, etc...).

In general, using a (logically) weaker foundation means there are more possibilities for things to be consistent with it, so we shouldn't expect that a weaker foundation will decide something that is undecidable in a stronger theory. Of course, in another sense logically weaker foundations are "stronger" because it's harder to get an inconsistency out of them and we are less likely to need to change our proofs in the future if an inconsistency were discovered.

@RobertFurber until one gets all the way down to self-verifying theories, of course: https://mathoverflow.net/a/10027/4177 Note that the statement to be proved is relative to the given theory, similarly to how versions of CH in different theories are really different statements.

In ETCS, the continuum hypothesis can be encoded as the statement that given a set $X$ with injections $\mathbb{N} \hookrightarrow X \hookrightarrow 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, then there is either an isomorphism $X\simeq \mathbb{N}$ or an isomorphism $X\simeq 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.
This formulation, perhaps with $\mathbb{R}$ (or $P(\mathbb{N})$ directly) in place of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, makes sense in any foundations that are strong enough to define the reals, or the function set as shown, or the power set of the naturals, as appropriate (one might have function sets and not power sets, for instance, in predicative foundations).
The CH is independent of the ETCS axioms, which was shown in the first substantial paper on using elementary topos axioms as a basis for a foundation, and how forcing is done using sheaves, by Lawvere and Tierney (the work was done jointly, they just published proceedings papers separately and credit each other):

William Lawvere, Quantifiers and sheaves, Actes, Congrès intern, math., 1970. Tome 1, p. 329 à 334 (pdf)

Myles Tierney, Sheaf theory and the continuum hypothesis, In: Lawvere, F.W. (eds) Toposes, Algebraic Geometry and Logic. Lecture Notes in Mathematics 274 Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 1972. https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0073963



I realise this is not exactly "non-set-theoretic foundations", since ETCS is a theory of sets, but I'm taking the question more broadly as asking what happens in foundations that are not ZFC or extensions thereof.

One consideration will be that the CH statement can become ambiguous in weaker foundations, since statements that are equivalent in ZFC are not always equivalent in weaker theories.
For example, without the axiom of choice, then taking CH as the assertion that the reals have cardinality $\aleph_1$ is not equivalent to the assertion that there is no cardinality strictly between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.
For example, in ZF+AD, the situation is that CH fails in that the reals are not bijective with $\aleph_1$, since they are not well-orderable at all, and yet CH holds in that there is no set of reals of intermediate cardinality, since every every uncountable set of reals contains a perfect set, and these are always bijective with $\mathbb{R}$.
Several of the alternative foundational systems you mention do not routinely assume the axiom of choice, and so to talk about CH one needs to clarify which form of the principle one is considering.

This phenomenon of ‘losing the ability to talk about something’ as we move to weaker foundations is curious; I dream of working over a system with no axioms, but wonder how I would ever talk about anything.

@AlecRhea: You would end up proving that you can't talk about things. For instance, intuitionistically you cannot even exhibit a reasonable notion of size (measured by any linear order, such as $\mathbb{N}$) on subsingletons, which are sets $S$ satisfying $\forall x, y \in S ., x = y$. Infinite sets are worse.

@AndrejBauer: Agreed with the formal point, but I’d view it differently: There’s a perfectly good notion of size of sets, but intuitionistically you can’t show anything so unreasonably powerful as trichotomy for it!  (Sizes aren’t linearly ordered for physical objects — which is bigger, a sheet of A4 or an orange? — or for most other kinds of mathematical objects; so why should we expect them to be for sets?)

What is the reasonable notion of size you have in mind? I do not consider quotienting by isomorphism to be a notion of size. It's a notion of equality. Perhaps embeddability by injections? That's more reasonable, but still fairly strange (as it may happen that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ embed in each other etc.)

@AndrejBauer Without CSB, you don't know injections alone are a good comparison of size, of course.

@AndrejBauer: Yes, I did mean embeddability by injections (or, if you want, that modulo quotienting by isomorphism).  It certainly satisfies fewer formal properties in the absence of choice/LEM, but it’s still a perfectly cromulent preorder, and (at least to my taste) seems reasonable to think of in terms of “size”.  Compare how mathematicians often speak of “bigger”/“smaller” in the context of spaces, algebraic objects, etc., where trichotomy and the analogue of Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein certainly don’t hold.

Sure, we can go that way, but you won't be able to show that $\mathbb{N}$ is smaller than $\mathbb{R}$, nor that $\mathbb{R}$ is not smaller than $\mathbb{N}$, and in fact it's possible to have injections both ways simultaneously. Perhaps a good way to proceed would be to have a specific goal in mind. What would we like to accomplish with these sizes? The classical treatment initiated by Cantor yields a coherent picture with many deep results. Can we paint a picture that doesn't look like a Salvador Dalí on psychadelic drugs?
